# is there a way to find who read the data in the last 60 days in particular HDFS Path?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to find the usage of HDFS path
I have the hdfs path, is there a way i can find who read the data in the last 60 days?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it directly with the hadoop fs shell. We passed through this before and what we did was implement it using the https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html directly to access this information.

```
Path path = new Path(yourfolder)
FileStatus fileStatus = fs.getFileStatus(path);
for (FileStatus stat : fs.listStatus(fileStatus.getPath())) {
   fs.getAccessTime() // this give you the last access
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @lake. Let me try this

Answer (score 0):

The hdfs-audit log would capture those information for you.

- If user ls a file or dir, it logs an entry like

  2017-02-23 17:56:36,019 INFO FSNamesystem.audit: allowed=true   ugi=hdfs (auth:SIMPLE)  ip=/172.16.151.224      cmd=listStatus  src=/tmp        dst=null        perm=null       proto=rpc
- If user cat a file, it logs an entry like

  2017-02-23 17:56:45,384 INFO FSNamesystem.audit: allowed=true   ugi=hdfs (auth:SIMPLE)  ip=/172.16.151.224      cmd=open        src=/tmp/file    dst=null        proto=rpc